# Docker image doesn't work after installing sample data Magento 2

Tags: php, docker, magento, magento2

I installed docker and after that installed Magento 2 bitnami image (in the list of images i can see magento, elasticsearch, mariadb). I entered magento image by id. Deleted temporary files and cache. Created admin user. Then i use`php bin/magento sampledata:deploy`. Sampledata installed. After that i use `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento cache:flush` exit from the console and my magento image crashed. I cant restart it. I tried to delete it and download one more time - it doesnt help. I should delete docker and install everything one more time to run the image. And every time got the same issue. I looked into logs and see the same logs every time. Docker crashed after trying to update database schema [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNNLr.png).

What can i do? I tried to add memory to docker. Delete images and download them. Delete docker and start from the scratch - the same result. Please, help me

Comment: I have also same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: How are you "bringing up" the container? Are you using docker-compose, or CLI with `docker run...`? Please edit your question with these details instead of replying to this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue like you.
It seems to be a permissions issue, to fix it, under the magento root directory (in my case /bitnami/magento, as I'm using a bitnami docker image). Check, or directly set, the mod and ownership for the following:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
sudo chown -R 1001:1001 var/ pub/ generated/
```

PS.: In my case I configured persistence, so even docker container was unable to start, I could fix it by doing it on the local persistence path. This way, once permissions were fixed, the container was able to start again.

I hope it helps.

Update:
In order to complete the answer, the problem is that when you connects to docker terminal, you are probably connecting as root, instead of like magento user. This is why we must change the ownership.
An alternative solution, is to connect with the user for magento, I mean:

- After connecting to magento terminal, impersonate, in my case, the user is named "daemon", so:

```
su daemon -s /bin/bash
```

Once you are connected as the user daemon in my case, execute all the actions you want to do: load sampledata, this way the directories will have the right permissions. Anyhow, check them after running your actions.